# Overlapping Elements in a List Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to get the elements of the listview to overlap slightly. Is this possible in the standard listview?

Here is my Xaml:

```
<StackLayout Padding="10, 10, 10, 10">
    <StackLayout>
        <ListView HasUnevenRows="True"            
                  SeparatorColor="Blue"
                  x:Name="cardsList">
        </ListView>

    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

and this is my code behind:

```
 var cards = new List<string> {"card 1","card 2","card 3","card 4" };


        // stacklayout.Children.Add(listView);

        cardsList.ItemsSource = cards;
        cardsList.RowHeight = 150;
```

the code is very minimal and this is only a proof of concept. This gives the standard list with some height but not quite what im looking for. This is what im trying to achieve:[image]

I realise that I'm not going to be able to get that exactly that or probably close to it. But this kind of effect. It doesnt need to be a listview, it can be a grid or even a nuget package that does it. Any ideas?

Comment: Your image example doesn't render for me so I'm not entirely sure visibly what you're after. However I would assume you could provide a custom `ListView.ItemTemplate` wherein on the data template's parent panel you could specify a negative top margin so that upon render it would follow the natural z-index layering as the items are added to the DOM to produce the effect you're after. Left just as comment because I won't have time to test today. :)

Comment: I will look at that. That example above is just a bog standard list view example nothing specific. It was just a base to start with. But I will look look at this. I did try setting the margin of the list view itself but it just off sets the whole thing not the individual elements of the list.

Comment: I think something like this might work:
https://github.com/nishanil/Xamarin.Forms-Samples/tree/master/DataTemplateSelector/DataTemplateSelector/DataTemplateSelector

Comment: Oh that's a nifty interface and could be done, but unfortunately I wouldn't have enough free time to build that out at the moment. Too busy with my own work lol. You're on the right track with the datatemplate selection though.

Comment: I did give this a try but it seems that actually getting the elements in the listview to overlap cant be done? Although it might just be my lack of experience but I couldnt get it to work. Its nice to get all the individual elements all customised but actually affecting the z-index is tough.